# Ionic/Cordova: programmatically set app version

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

The version number of a Cordova app can be set in the `<widget>` element of `config.xml`, but is there a way to set it programmatically?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <widget defaultLocale="en-US" id="com.example.myapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
      <name>MyApp</name>
...
```

I would like to set the version number during the build, using the build number as the version number. It would be nice if we could change config.xml programmatically at build time, e.g. by running a Cordova cli command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Gulp, it can be done by using a plugin like [gulp-xmlpoke](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-xmlpoke).

You can pass the build version to gulp via commandline arguments (e.g. `gulp --buildVersion=1.2.3`) and extract them with [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs).

Example gulp task:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var argv = require("yargs").argv;    
var xmlpoke = require("gulp-xmlpoke");

gulp.task("setAppVersion", function () {
        return gulp.src("config.xml")
            .pipe(xmlpoke({
                replacements: [{
                    xpath: "/w:widget/@version",
                    value: argv.buildVersion,
                    namespaces: { "w": "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets", "cdv": "http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" }
                }]
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
    });
```

Comment: Hi, any other way of achieving this without using gulp?
I need to update the widget id and version, when the hook script is running.